# Swift 2: reading from a file

Tags: arrays, string, swift, file, translation

I've created this small translation between English and Spanish words. If the user enters "the cat" it will print "el gato" by checking the index number. I would like to know if there's any way I can read from a file that contains more words.

File 1 (English)
File 2 (Spanish)

File 1 will check "hello" in file 2 "Hola" and print the correct translation

```
import UIKit

class translateViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var translateTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var translateButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var translateLabel: UILabel!

var englishArray: [String] = ["the cat", "the dog", "hello", ]
var spanishArray: [String] = ["el gato", "el perro", "hola"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func translateButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    let emptyString = self.translateTextField.text

    if (emptyString!.isEmpty) {

        print("please enter a word")

    }

    for transIndex in englishArray.indices {
        if englishArray[transIndex] == emptyString!.lowercaseString {

            translateLabel.text = "\(spanishArray[transIndex])"

            print(transIndex)
            return

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Sorry.. completely missed that "swift" mention. I must be drunk :s**

Either add more words in the array or if you want to do filing i don't think you'll need 2 files... it'd be better if you store words like

`hello = hola`

then do some string processing to check words before `=` If they match, print the word after `=`

OR an easier way would be...

You could store words like

`Hello
 Hola
 The cat
 El gato`

Then do this (somewhat a pseudo code)...

```
while(reader.hasNextline())
{
   if (reader.readline().Equals(input_word))  // read the first line and check if it matches the input word
   {
      System.out.println(reader.readline());  // print translated word which on the next line
      break;
   }
   reader.readline();  // If it doesn't matches then skip the spanish translation on the next line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way for this purpose is `Localizable.strings` and `NSLocalizedString()`

---

- Create a file `Localizable.strings`
- Populate the strings file with key/value pairs for example (the syntax including the semicolons is mandatory even in Swift).

  ```
  "the cat" = "el gato";
  "the dog" = "el perro";
  "hello" = "hola";
  ```
- Translate words/expressions with `NSLocalizedString()`

  ```
  translateLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(emptyString!.lowercaseString, comment:"")
  ```

`NSLocalizedString()` retrieves the value `el gato` for key `the cat`

Comment: what about for words that are not in the array list but inside Localizable.strings? It doesn't retrieve the value only words in the array. @vadian

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: say I have an array = ["the cat", " the dog"] but inside my localizable.string I have: "hello" = "hola"; When I type in "hello" in my textField it doesn't retrieve the value "hello" in translateLabel.text @vadian

Comment: All items to be translated must be in the array you compare the entered text with **and** in the .strings file

Comment: my English array will be long, would it be best to read the array from a file? @vadian

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. Use a simple .txt file with one item per line or a property list file.

Comment: I'm going to use the property list do you know how I can link this to my englishArray? @vandian

Comment: Create the array in code and use the `writeToFile` or `writeToURL` method on `NSArray`. It saves the array as property list on disk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110009/discussion-between-sam-and-vadian).